# How to check for a value, that was submitted in a form and sends through AJAX call, in PHP file

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, isset

I am wanting to do an `INSERT` query in my php file for users that were put into the group #3. I know with PHP you can check if a button was pressed or if something isset, but how can you check a value was sent and passed through with AJAX?

So, let's say I changed the group level to 3 (the group levels are determined through the value option in the form). How can I make my query check that was the option selected?

Form

```
<div class="change_group_button"> 
 <a class="change_group" href="javascript:void(0)">Change User 

Permission</a>
</div><br>
<div id="light" class="change_group_popup">
    <a class="close" href="javascript:void(0)">Close</a>
 <div class="group_success" style="color: red;"></div><br>
    <form id="update_group" action="" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
       <div class="field">
        <label for="group">Group</label>
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $approved_id; ?>" id="approved_id" name="id" />
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $approved_firstname; ?>" id="approved_firstname" name="firstname" />
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $approved_lastname; ?>" id="approved_lastname" name="lastname" />
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $approved_username; ?>" id="approved_username" name="username" />
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $approved_email; ?>" id="approved_email" name="email" />
        <select id='group_id' name='group' required>
            <option value=''><?php echo htmlentities($group); ?></option>
            <option value="1">Bench</option>
            <option value="2">Spectator</option>
            <option value="3">Team Member</option>
            <option value="4">Commissioner</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="group">
    </form>
```

AJAX call

```
$('#update_group').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'user_group_update.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
            id: $("#approved_id").val(), //id
            firstname: $("#approved_firstname").val(), //firstname
            lastname: $("#approved_lastname").val(), //lastname
            username: $("#approved_username").val(), //username
            email: $("#approved_email").val(), //email
           // update_group: $("#group_id").val() //group level
          update_group: $(this).find( "#group_id option:selected" ).val()
        },
            success: function (data) {
                //do something with the data that got returned
                $(".group_success").fadeIn();
                $(".group_success").show();
                $('.group_success').html('User Permission Level Changed!');
                $('.group_success').delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
                alert(data);
            },
             error: function(jqXHR, textStatus,errorThrown )
            {
              // alert on an http error 
              alert( textStatus +  errorThrown );
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

In my PHP file I get these fields from the form..

```
$approved_id = $_POST['id'];
//test - delete if it doesn't work
$approved_firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$approved_lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$approved_username = $_POST['username'];
$approved_email = $_POST['email'];
$change_group = $_POST['update_group'];
```

Comment: ajax isn't magical. it's just a regular plain http request, like any OTHER http request, that just happens to be performed in the "background" of a browser, instead of "in your face" like most form submissions.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking... The value you're looking for is in your `$change_group` variable, isn't it?  What exactly isn't working here?

Comment: Nothing. Just check for values in `$_POST`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PHP file that receives the POST, you can do your value checking:

```
$approved_id = $_POST['id'];

if($approved_id == '3')
{
    //do something
}
else
{
    //do something else
}
//test - delete if it doesn't work
$approved_firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$approved_lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$approved_username = $_POST['username'];
$approved_email = $_POST['email'];
$change_group = $_POST['update_group'];
```

Comment: I have another query in my PHP file that needs the value of the group (group #) no matter what it is. So if I would put this under that query would that be fine?

Comment: Yes, as far as I can tell that should work.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check if your script was POST'ed to and make sure POST isnt empty to make sure it contains data like so:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && !empty($_POST) ) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript frameworks, such as jQuery, send a special header with the POST request for AJAX - so you can do this:

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
   // your code
}
```

Some programming frameworks, like [CodeIgniter](http://www.codeigniter.com), have their own functions to make it easier:

```
$this->input->is_ajax_request();
```

Remember it can be spoofed.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to secure your ajax call. generate token and match that token in controller. these are available in every framework.
if you want to do this in custom PHP than you should make session in your page load and match this session in your post request.